# What is the sentiment inside the United Russia party now?

Tags: russian-federation, parties, ukraine

The [United Russia party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Russia) controls its country,
so I assume that most people affiliated with this party support the Ukraine occupation.
Has anyone in this party publicly come out opposing the Ukraine occupation?
In an anonymous survey across members of this party who hold a political office, roughly what
percentage would oppose it?

I can't even find a public statement from the [Prime Minister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Mishustin), but assume he would both publicly and
anonymously support it.

(Of course, it's impossible to get inside peoples' heads, so I will settle for an answer with
just some public statements.  I only ask about anonymous surveys because I'd rather not measure
the effects of political pressures.)

Comment: "In an anonymous survey across members of this party who hold a political office, roughly what percentage would oppose it?" Nobody knows. How could anyone answer it?

Comment: @Trilarion I tried to explain why I asked this way in my final sentence...guess you didn't read that far.

Comment: I read that far, but I also think that it's useless to ask for something you cannot get an answer for and then say, well then don't answer it. This just makes the question longer without any benefit. I really think that nobody can answer that part of your question because of there not being such a survey that's also credible. I would actually leave it out in the question.

Comment: @Trilarion As an outsider, I mainly want to know if anybody in United Russia opposes Putin.  I suppose I could have just asked that, but then I was thinking the answers would vaguely say there is too much pressure to say anything else, leaving me still with nothing.

Comment: Many people would like to know what's going on inside the heads of Russians right now but unfortunately there is no good way to know this. There is unfortunately not enough information about that existing and any error would be huge (like the complete opposite could be true). We can ask much more questions than we can answer realistically. That's why I first asked you here what you would imagine an answer to be. Relevant meta discussion: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/questions-about-the-current-attitude-of-russians-which-might-not-be-possible-to

Comment: While it could be an interesting question on some forums where it can be discused, it seems not really to be suitable for stackexchange, as no fact based answer can be given.

Comment: @convert  I think it was wrong to close this question.  A fact-based answer was given. These are the politics that a lot of us care about.  It just takes one person inside Russia to answer here and enlighten us.  I was hoping for spoken/written quotes, so it would not have been speculation.  As it stands, I will assume everyone in the United Russia party supports Putin.  But, this is surprising since I have been to Russia and then found that the people freely spoke their minds, so I would have expected more controversy and public dialog among the politicians...

Comment: @bobuhito Shure there are people in Russia who hate Putin and they tallk about it, but they all are opposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it happens that [two of United Russia parliament members](https://zavtra.ru/events/davajte_poimyonno_kto_iz_deputatov_gosdumi_rf_progolosoval_protiv_priznaniya_ldnr) voted "against" and one "abstained" on the recognition of LDNR. A lot more choose not to participate by being absent.

Comment: How many parliament members does United Russia have?

Comment: I guess more than 300 out of 450, you can check on Wikipedia.